# exc_arm_breakpoint crash with CFRelease when connected to gmail-contacts

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have code like:

```
ABMultiValueRef multiPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
CFRelease(multiPhones);
```

My app on device crashes when I connect device to my gmail account.

If I remove the gmail (CONTACTS) account or remove CFRelease statement, it does not crash.

Please provide pointers to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually for future references, I re-opened and answered

Reason was CFRelease(null)